# can you use concatenate function in excel to add leading zeros depending on a number in another cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to find a way to insert leading zeros into an excel cell dependant on the size of another cell for example

if cell A1 = 21 and cell b1 = 8 I want A1 to equal 00000021 or
if cell A2 = 1  and cell b2 = 8 I want A2 to equal 00000001

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear when/how you want this to run, but the gist is:

```
activecell.NumberFormat = string(activecell.Offset(, 1).Value, "0")
```

To have this happen automatically when you adjust the numbers in column B, right-click the worksheet tab, choose View Code and paste this in:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rCell                 As Range
    On Error GoTo clean_up
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each rCell In Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")).Cells
            If IsNumeric(rCell) Then Cells(rCell.Row, "A").NumberFormat = String(rCell.Value2, "0")
        Next rCell
    End If

clean_up:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Edit: I've adjusted the code to hopefully make the columns easier to adapt.

Comment: from my previous example I would like the cells to just update instantly when edited so that if B1 was changed, the number that was already in A1 would have the number of leading zero's before it change accordingly if that makes any sense? @Rory

Comment: Will this code be specific to that example I gave because I may need to edit which columns are used for example I need it  for F1 instead of B1 and will having a heading in the first row effect the result do I need to edit it so that it ignores the first row ? @Rory

Comment: @pnuts I don't know - may you? ;)

Comment: @leo.genuardi As long as the number to format is in the column to the left, you just need to change `Columns(2)` to whichever column number has the number of digits to display.

Comment: How about if the number to format is in column A and column F holds the number of leading zeros I need added ? @Rory

Comment: @leo.genuardi I've edited the code to hopefully make it simpler to adapt.

Answer (score 1):

The Excel-only formula for it is shown here:

```
=REPT(0,A2-LEN(A1))&A1
```

The formula creates a string with the needed amount of zeros and concatenates the number to the zeros. Of course, you need this formula in a cell other than A1.

The '&' does concatenation. You can also use the concatenate function:

```
=CONCATENATE(REPT(0,A2-LEN(A1)),A1)
```

Comment: Or use `TEXT`:  `=TEXT(A1,REPT("0",B1))`